# Nginx upstream and listen of the same port

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have configured `nginx` on an EC2 instance.

I am running `rabbitmq-management` which is running on port `15672` and is accessible using the IP address of the instance.

```
http://ip-address:15672
```

I do not want to allow access using the IP address and want to use my domain  but using the same port as

```
http://utils.example.com:15672
```

For that, I tried to configure the `nginx` server with configuration

```
upstream rabbitmq_server {
    server localhost:15672;
}


server {

  listen      15672 ssl;
  server_name utils.example.com;

  location / {
      proxy_pass          http://rabbitmq_server/;
      proxy_redirect      off;
      proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
  }
}
```

But, this is giving error on starting the `nginx` server as

```
[emerg] 7476#7476: bind() to 0.0.0.0:15672 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

When I change the port to `listen 15673`, it works and is accessible using the domain also but is accessible using the IP address also.

1. How can I use the same internal IP on which application is running to be accessible from `http://utils.example.com`?
2. How can I disable direct access from the IP address and restrict access to domain/sub-domain only?

Comment: You can not have two application using the same port. You can have nginx on another server and upstream to the rabbit mq server then have some firewall rules on it to only allow on that port from your nginx server

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IF and check the $host variable inside the location, you can find the IF guide for nginx here
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Result would be similar to this one

```
upstream rabbitmq_server {
    server localhost:15672;
}


server {

listen      15672 ssl;
server_name utils.example.com;

location / {
    if ($host = utils.example.com) {
        proxy_pass          http://rabbitmq_server/;
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it still fail because you are trying to get the same port? Plus server_name utils.example.com;
 already filters the domain

Answer (score 0):

1)How can I use the same internal IP on which application is running to be accessible from http://utils.example.com?

You can't have those 2 applicacions (nginx and rabbit) listening to the same port.

sending a petition to ip: http://utils.example.com:15672 and http://ip:15672 is the same (not exactly, but for the example it will work).

My recomendation:

Change rabbitmq port to another one, lets say 15673. and set the nginx config like this:

```
upstream rabbitmq_server {
    server localhost:15673;
}


server {

    listen      15672 ssl;
    server_name utils.example.com your_ip_numbers;

    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://rabbitmq_server/;
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
    }
}
```

Like this, both your_ip:15672 and utils.example.com:15672 will go through nginx to be proxied to rabbitmq.

2) How can I disable direct access from the IP address and restrict access to domain/sub-domain only?

Take out "your_ip_numbers" from the server_name directive if you are going to use the recomendation and block any access to port 15673 in the firewall. Localhost proxies are not considered as a normal connection by most firewalls.

And if you only have proxy to rabbitmq to the server bracket of server_name utils.example.com; that's already a way to filter only this subdomain connections to rabbitmq.

If I have not expressed myself correctly, ask me in the comments what I'm refering to, I'd be glad to answer

Edit:

For the ip not to be proxy_passed, creating another default_server bracket in the same port (it's nginx so they don't collide) will send the ip there.

```
server {

    listen      15672 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 418; #(or really any code you like) 
}
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: 2. I haven't added the `IP` address in the `server_name` but still it is accessible from `IP` address. I don't think it will have any effect by adding and removing IP from the `server_name`

Comment: @AnujTBE Just added a server conf to return an error code to the ip requests.

Comment: If I add the `return` to the base configuration, will it work on all ports?. I have multiple ports serving multiple applications, just want a one use solution.

Comment: the listen 15672 ssl default_server; means that it only listens to 15672 , accepts ssl connections, and it's the default_server for this port, not all the nginx configuration.

If you don't feel right about this, just change the server_name from _ to your ip, and take out the "default_server". like this it will only get "ip:15672" like connections

the return 418 it's inside one single server bracket, that listens to a single port. not all of them